# Destructor, graph and recursivity

Tags: c++, recursion, vector, tree

I have a graph object and i would like to create a destructor for this. However, i'm not really confortable with recursivity and i'm a bit lost in my own data structures. I'll show the classes involved and my beginning of destructor.

```
class Graph {

private :
        Graph*               parent;
        vector<Graph>        child;
        Board                tab;
        bool                 seen;

public :
        Graph(const Board&);
        Graph(const Board&, Graph*);
        ~Graph();
        ...
};

class Board {        
    private :
        int**           tab;
        int             nbline;
        int             nbcolumn;
        Position        emptyspot;

    public  :
        Board();
        Board(int, int, Play&);
        Board(int, int);
        Board(const Board&);
        Board(int, int, ifstream&);
        ~Board();
       ...
};
```

Position class only got 2 int (line and columns). 
The Board destructor works :

```
Board::~Board()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < this->nbline; i++) {
        delete tab[i];
    }
    delete tab;
}
```

As you guessed, i would like to destroy a node of my graph, and all the following nodes.

Here is my beggining :

```
Graph::~Graph() {        
    while(!child.empty()) {                
        for(vector<Graph>::iterator itr = child.begin; itr != child.end; ++itr) {
            delete child[itr];
        }
    }
}
```

This way I go into all of my branch, recursively, right? When I find a leaf (vector is null) - if destroy everything, what will happen in the vector of the parent ?

I don't know if the parent will set himself at NULL (i don't think so), and parent vector memory space won't be unallocated so the condition child.empty() won't be fulfilled, right ?

- How and when do I destroy the *Graph ?
- Do I risk a stack overflow ?

  - Can I call `vector.erase()` in the root-node where I start deleting, in order to destroy everything recursively instead of doing the for-loop ?

Comment: is child a vector<Graph> or a vector<Graph*>?  You have `vector<Graph>` but you are calling delete so I'm confused.

Comment: It's a mistake of mine, it should be vector<Graph*>, i'll have to change the constructors too ^^'

Answer (score 3):

Your destructor is incorrect for lots of reasons.

1. Your `child` member should probably be `vector<Graph*>` so that you can actually `delete` them.
2. Your loop is infinite if your `Graph` has any children since you are never changing the *size* of the `child` vector.
3. `child[itr]` is not how you get the `Graph*` corresponding to the iterator, `*itr` is.
4. `begin` and `end` are member functions, so they need to be called.
5. The member should probably be named `children`, no?

The correct loop would be:

```
for (vector<Graph*>::iterator itr = children.begin(); itr != children.end(); ++itr) {
    delete *itr; // this will recursively call Graph::~Graph() 
                 // on the children, and then free their memory
}
```

Or, in C++11, we simply define:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Graph>> children;
```

So that the memory cleanup would be handled for us.

Comment: @Csi: If you do not have C++11 capabilities, check [Boost Smart Pointers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm). They are the same thing, basically, implemented with C++98 means.

Comment: @DevSolar I don't have the right to use Boost ;_; Teacher is very old school :'(

Comment: @DevSolar Thx buddy :-)  I made an answer to the topic with modifications after people advice, is it correct now ?